# How to approximate $PV\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan x}{x}\text{d}x?$

Tags: numerical-integration, approximation

What's the mathematica command to get the **numerical value** of  :

$$PV\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan x}{x}\text{d}x?$$

where $PV$ is the principal value.

Comment: Have you looked at `NIntegrate` yet?

Comment: @b3m2a1 yes.. didnt work and also tried the WorkingPrecision and still nothing.

Comment: It might be of interest to others, I suppose, that the double exponential oscillatory method can be used to get an OK result on this integrand that has periodic simple poles: `Pi/2 - NIntegrate[(Tan[x]/x - Tan[x]/(Round[x + Pi/2, Pi] - Pi/2)), {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> {"DoubleExponentialOscillatory", "TuningParameters" -> {1, 5}}, MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The integral is `Pi/2`, a proof of which may be found on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141437/the-principal-value-of-an-integral).  Here's a numerical check, integrating $(\tan z)/z$ over parallel paths $z = x \pm a i$ and subtracting $(2 a)/(a^2 + x^2)$ to get `NIntegrate` to converge.  The OP's integral is equal to the sum of the two below.

```
a = 50;
1/2 NIntegrate[
  Tan[x + a I]/(x + a I) + Tan[x - a I]/(x - a I) -
     (2 a)/(a^2 + x^2) //
    ComplexExpand // Simplify,
  {x, 0, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 16]
1/2 Integrate[(2 a)/(a^2 + x^2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0]
(*
  -7.83867*10^-47
  Pi/2
*)
```

*Update*

It was late and I was tired. A shortcut (due to the symmetry of `Tan[x]/x`) occurred to me this morning:

```
a = 50;
NIntegrate[Re[Tan[x]/x], {x, 0 + a I, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]

(*  1.5707963267948966192313216916397514399782555923723  *)
```

Comment: Thank you. So we have to manipulate the integrand? The answer (pi/2 ) is well -known but my point is to learn the command to approximate more advanced PV integrals such such $PV \int_0^\infty (\tan x/x)^3 dx.$

Comment: @AliShadhar One of the ideas is to deform the path of integration to go around both sides of a pole in the complex plane (to get the PV).  Whether that works numerically depends on the function. Here I took advantage of some symmetry in $\tan x/x$ because of the route I took; in fact, `NIntegrate[Re[Tan[x]/x], {x, 0 + a I, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 16, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` is simpler.  Note that $(\tan x/x)^3$ has a nonzero coefficient of $(x-x_0)^{-2}$ in its Laurent expansion at a pole; so it does not have a principal value (in the traditional sense as I know it).

Comment: Thank you Michael. your update is much simpler. By the way, a friend claimed that he mathematically proved that the $PV \int_0^\infty (\tan x/x)^3 dx$ converges which is the reason I am trying to verify such claim on mathematica.

Comment: @AliShadhar Your friend is perhaps using a different definition of PV.  For instance $PV \int_0^\pi (\tan x/x)^3\,dx$ diverges to $+\infty$, as it does at each pole. (Numerical check: `Table[NIntegrate[(Tan[x]/x)^3, {x, 0, Pi/2 - 10^-k}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 20] + NIntegrate[(Tan[x]/x)^3, {x, Pi/2 + 10^-k, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 20], {k, 10}]` shows clearly the contribution of the `48/(Pi^4 (x - Pi/2)^2)` term of the Laurent series.)

Comment: @Ali, are you sure your friend was not confusing the [Hadamard finite part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization) with the Cauchy principal value?

Comment: @J. M. thank you for the Link. I will let my friend know about this.

Answer (score 6):

You can evaluate principal-valued integrals using NIntegrate using Method->"PrincipalValue" but you must specify the singular point(s).  In your case, there are an infinite number of them.  For starters, integrating over just the first one at $\pi/2$, we can write:

```
NIntegrate[Tan[x]/x, {x, 0, Pi/2, 3}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

Out[42]= 1.36501
```

Notice how I inserted the first singular point $\pi/2$ between the limits of integration.  If we wanted to integrate over two of them, then:

```
In[44]:= NIntegrate[Tan[x]/x, {x, 0, Pi/2, 3 Pi/2, 6}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

Out[44]= 1.46884
```

And if I wanted to integrate over 25 singular points, I would sequence-in a table of 25 singular points into the limits of integration and notice in the plot below it's convergence to $\pi/2$:

```
totalN = 25;
myTable = Table[
   {index, 
    NIntegrate[
     Tan[x]/x, {x, 0, 
      Sequence @@ Table[Pi/2 + n Pi, {n, 0, index}], (index + 1) Pi}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue"]},
   {index, 0, totalN}];
ListPlot[myTable, Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot of principal-valued integrals]

Comment: Thank you Dominic for the efforts. +1

Answer (score 3):

The method `"PrincipalValue"` does not work on an integral with infinitely many poles, since each pole must be specified.  Confining to a finite region of integration is problematic on integrals like $\int_0^\infty (\tan x/x)\,dx$ that converge slowly.  `NIntegrate` has built in the `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` strategy, but even if it would work together with the `"PrincipalValue"` strategy, you would still have the problem of specifying infinitely many poles.  Instead, we can manually call `NSum` on the principal value integral over each period of `Tan[x]`. `NSum` will do the extrapolation for us.  (Something similar was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147959/4999) and is shown [in the documenation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#50593814).)  The series still converges slowly, and the results are not as good as my other answer.

```
ClearAll[cc];
cc[n_Integer] := cc[n] =
   NIntegrate[Tan[x]/x, {x, 0 + n Pi, Pi/2 + n Pi, Pi + n Pi}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
    Method -> {"PrincipalValue", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}];

NSum[cc[n], {n, 0, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 50, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {1.76767, 1.57067}  *)
```

---

**Alternative**

We can speed up the principal value integral by subtracting a null integral that smashes the pole (something similar was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/214701/4999)).  The slow convergence persists, but the following is twice as fast as with the `"PrincipalValue"` method.

```
ClearAll[cc];
cc[n_Integer] := cc[n] = NIntegrate[
    Tan[x]/x - Tan[x]/(Pi/2 + n Pi), 
    {x, 0 + n Pi, Pi + n Pi}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"];

NSum[cc[n], {n, 0, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 1000, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {10.2142, 1.57078947}  *)

Last@% - Pi/2   (* error *)
(*  -6.85*10^-6  *)
```

Comment: Still, I thought it was cool to sequence-in all those singularities.  :)

Comment: @Dominic Yes, it was. Personally I like smashing the pole with `NIntegrate[Tan[x]/x - Tan[x]/(Pi/2 + n Pi), {x, 0 + n Pi, Pi + n Pi}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]`, which I didn't show. It doesn't perform better.

Comment: @Dominic Well, it is faster than `"PrincipalValue"`.